# update the time of a task that has already been created

Tags: c#, .net, windows-task-scheduler

I have problem with modifying tasks on my computer. I'm trying to do this with generated interop interfaces from C# (Interop.TaskScheduler.dll generated from system32/taskschd.dll)

I just want to change the time.

```
 void UpdateTaskDefintion(IRegisteredTask oldTask, TimeSpan ts)
    {
        ITaskDefinition newTask = oldTask.Definition;
        ITriggerCollection triggers = newTask.Triggers;
        IWeeklyTrigger trigger = (IWeeklyTrigger)triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_WEEKLY);
        trigger.Enabled = true;

        trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + ts.ToString();

        _rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(oldTask.Name, newTask, (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_UPDATE, null, null, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, null);
    }
```

When it gets to the last line it bugs out with the message, (29,8):DaysOfWeek. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE and answer**

Using the code below kind of works but not completely. It adds a new trigger to my scheduled task. So when I look at the Task Scheduler UI it now says Multiple triggers defined. So I added the line triggers.Remove(1) - the collection starts counting at 1 not 0.

```
 ITaskDefinition newTask = oldTask.Definition;
 ITriggerCollection triggers = newTask.Triggers;
 IWeeklyTrigger trigger =(IWeeklyTrigger)triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_WEEKLY);            
        trigger.Enabled = true;
        trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + ts.ToString();

        if (freq == enumFrequency.Daily)
            trigger.DaysOfWeek = 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32;                                   // 2 monday, 4 tuesday, 8 wednesday etc
        else
            trigger.DaysOfWeek = 2;

        trigger.WeeksInterval = 1;                        
            trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = triggers[0].ExecutionTimeLimit;
        triggers.Remove(1);         // for some unknow reason the first item in the collection is 1 not zero

        _rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(oldTask.Name, newTask, (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_UPDATE, null, null, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, null);
```

Comment: Did you see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592146/changing-run-time-of-already-scheduled-tasks-in-windows-task-scheduler) ?

Comment: @Michael yes I did thanks. Its not working for me. I've just updated my post though.