# In RabbitMQ is there a way to send messages to consumers at regular intervals?

Tags: rabbitmq

We are using RabbitMQ to send notifications to users on apps. So there is a consumer that will send the notification to all the users using the app.

when we have multiple messages in the queue, we want rabbitmq to send each messages at least 1 hour apart.

So if there are 3 messages in the queue, each message will be sent an hour apart.

If there are no new messages in the queue and a new message is published, then depending on when the last message was sent to a consumer it will either hold it or send it.

Is there any direct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, it's described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/). I'll just quote a one part:

> To delay a message a user must publish the message with the special
>   header called x-delay which takes an integer representing the number
>   of milliseconds the message should be delayed by RabbitMQ.

Also another approach (before rabbitmq added delays exchange) was using a combination of dead-letter exchange and message ttl as described [here](http://yuserinterface.com/dev/2013/01/08/how-to-schedule-delay-messages-with-rabbitmq-using-a-dead-letter-exchange/) for example.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The x-delay flag will work with respect to message. So say I publish a message at `t0` with a delay of `60 mins` Then that msg will be sent to queue after 60 mins. Now if I publish 3 msgs with the same delay then all these messages will be sent after 60 mins. What I want is that the first message gets sent at time `t0` the second at time `t0+60` and the third at `t0+120`. Correct me If i misunderstood your answer

Comment: Maybe:)Maybe I have misunderstood your comment. But the last part of your comment is exactly what I had in mind-you publish the message nr N and set the delay N*60. Obviously for the first message N=1.

Comment: So what you are saying is that while publishing the message set the delay for first msg as `0` then for 2nd msg set it `60` then `120`. That won't work for this case. Lets say the first message arrives at `t0` and i set the delay to `0`. Then If the second message comes at say `t0+100` then I would want the delay to be `0` and not `60`.

Comment: Ok, in that case no. I didn't realize that messages are coming the way you described now. You would have to track the timestamps on the publishing side. Maybe RMQ is not the way to go for your use case

Comment: Ya..found a workaround (have added an answer). If that can be improved let me know.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

1. Schedule cron for every 5 or "x" minutes.
2. Cron checks if there is a message in the queue, it extracts ONE messge from the queue. If notification is sent successfully, you can change the schedule of the cron to next run after 60 minutes (and after 5 or x minutes post that run). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592146/changing-run-time-of-already-scheduled-tasks-in-windows-task-scheduler) link for more information on rescheduling the window scheduled tasks.
3. Cron does nothing if there is no message in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon your question and wanted to have same thing with 10 second interval but was unable to do so while using channel.consume() methods.

I started reading the documentation and came to know that while using prefetch, queue will wait till the message is acked or nacked before sending another one.

So as a hack I gave timeout of 10 seconds to my ack/nack functionality and although my processing gets finished my consumer doesn't receive more messages since the last is still pending the acknowledgement.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_prefetch).

My sample code

```
 if (response) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("acking now ");
          pendingImportChannel.ack(pendingImportMessage);
        }, 10000);
        console.log("Pending import message acknowledged.");
      } else {
        console.log("Rejecting message => " + JSON.stringify(pendingImportDetails));
        setTimeout(() => {
          pendingImportChannel.nack(pendingImportMessage, false, true);
        }, 10000);
      }
```

Points to note

- Your prefetch value should be 1 (or number of messages you want to receive in one call)
- Make sure you don't ack/nack independently.
- Keep your acknowledgementStrategy as `noAck: false`. (feel free to experiment here)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I could not find a direct way to do it.

One way to achieve this is to write a cron job that runs every `60` mins (or what ever interval is required). The cron job will call a consumer that checks if there is a message in the queue. If there is, It will accept only one message, process it and then shut down.

The only disadvantage is that if the first message comes at `t0+1` then even though there were no messages process before it will wait for `60 minutes` before processing the message.

If this can be improved let me know.