# How to slow down a node/rabbitmq message/react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, rabbitmq

I have a simulated real time app. I send a csv file to rabbitmq. And rabbitmq sends back the queues. In my client app, ag grid cannot keep with the speed of the received messages. I am using websocket.
I wonder how can I control the speed of those messages, either in rabbitmq, node js, websocket in the server or client? I want to control the speed of each response, e.g. To send/receive every response every second, minute, etc.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184879/in-rabbitmq-is-there-a-way-to-send-messages-to-consumers-at-regular-intervals solved the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In RabbitMQ is there a way to send messages to consumers at regular intervals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184879/in-rabbitmq-is-there-a-way-to-send-messages-to-consumers-at-regular-intervals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to control the flow of the queues. Use prefetch to indicate how many queues you want to consume at each time, and add a set time to indicate how often

```
channel.prefetch(1);

channel.consume(
      queue,
      msg => {
        if (msg !== null) {
          if(msg) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(msg.content.toString());
              sendQueuesToWebSocket(msg.content.toString());
              channel.ack(msg);
            }, 50)
          } 
        } else {
          console.log('Consumer cancelled by server');
        }
      },
      {
        noAck: false,
      }
    );
```

Comment: Do no post links to other StackOverflow answers, or only duplicate code from another answer, as a new answer. When you have a high enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), from making quality contributions, you will be able to leave [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or [flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as duplicates. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32490376)